# Unable to implement UIPopoverController delegation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, delegates, uipopovercontroller

I have the following view controller in my UIPopover:

```
@protocol StorePopoverDelegate
- (void)storeSelected:(NSString *)store;
@end

@interface StorePopoverViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray* items;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<StorePopoverDelegate> delegate;


@end
```

When an item is selected I want my delegate to get called:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (delegate != nil) {
        [delegate storeSelected:[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
}
```

The delegate class that handles storeSelected is implemented:

```
-(IBAction)storesButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    storesPopoverViewController = [[StorePopoverViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    storePopover.delegate = (id)self;
    storePopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:storesPopoverViewController]; 
    [storePopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}

#pragma Store Popover Delegate Methods
- (void)storeSelected:(NSString *)store;
{
    NSLog(@"%@ was clicked", store);
    [storePopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

In my `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` the delegate is nil. I'm not sure why? I am assigning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `storesButtonClicked:` method you are setting the delegate of the `storePopover` (which is not even initialized at that point).  You should be setting the delegate property of `storePopoverViewController` instead.

```
storePopoverViewController.delegate = (id)self;
```